# Firebase Google log in - View not in hierarchy segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add a function inside the AppDelegate that segues to the next storyboard when the user is not already signed in however I keep getting the error "view is not in hierarchy". Where's the error in this code?

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {

        let _: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)

        self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeView2", sender: nil)

        return
    }
```

Comment: Why you don;'t change rootviewcontroller directly ? instead perform segue

Comment: UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil) need to change name here from "Main" to new Storyboard name "OtherName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying your "view is not in hierarchy", I think you should try below code. But I am not sure because I don't know the whole structure of your application. Hopefully it will work for you.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {

        let HomeView2Controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView2")
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeView2Controller!)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navController

        return
    }
}
```

Add navigation controller if required, else skip `navController` and directly set `HomeView2Controller` as your `rootViewController`

Cheers!